# fgets function printing garbage at the end

Tags: c, fgets

I had made a program that creates a file with name given by a user.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
       int g;
       char file[15];
       fgets(file,15,stdin);
       g=open(file,O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,__S_IWRITE);


}
```

But it creates a file with a filename with some garbage character at the end. How can I correct this?

here is sample run:

```
$ ./a.out
coolfile.txt
$ ls
a.out  coolfile.txt?  test.c
```

the same program but just using gets function gives correct filename but I had heard that gets should not be used.

Comment: Currently, there is no call to a write function in the code and please show us the content of the file. Also, you should always close your file descriptors after opening one.

Comment: `fgets()` retains the `'\n'`.  Likely that character is a problem for printable file names

Comment: @PhilippGrassl File is empty.I had used cat command

Comment: Add `#include <string.h>` then just `fgets(file,sizeof file,stdin); size_t len = strlen (file); if (len && file [len - 1] == '\n') file[--len] = 0; ...` That will overwrite any `'\n'` with a *nul-terminating* character (`'\0'` or the simple equivalent '0').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` stores `\n` at th end of each line thus you need remove that `\n`

to dot this use `strcspn` function

thus your code should look like this

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int main()
  {
    int g;
    char file[15];
    fgets(file,15,stdin);
    file[strcspn(file, "\n")] = 0;
    g=open(file,O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,__S_IWRITE);
  }
```

You can see more information about `strcspn` on :- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcspn.htm

Also refer this :- [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` stores the newline at the end of each line in the result.  So you are creating files whose names end with a newline character.  To fix it, simply check the last character and set it to `'\0'` if it was `'\n'`.